# bottle conditioning ale below room temperature

Tags: carbonation, temperature, bottle-conditioning

After bottling my batch of Porter, I forgot it need to be conditioned at room temperature. I left it in my garage for almost a week at 45-50°. When I realized what I had done, I moved it inside the house for about 10 days. When I sampled one, I didn't have much carbonation. Now what?

Answer (score 3):

Be patient.  It will carb, it will just take longer.  Wait another week or so, then start sampling to see if it's carbed yet.